# Android - Apache Ftps - SSLException

Tags: android, apache, ssl, ftp, ftps

I am trying to use Apache's `FTPSClient` to upload a file to a local ftp server.

I am setting `trustManager = TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager()` for now, as i do not yet want to deal with the unsigned certificate on the server. After connecting I try to upload a file with `storeFile(...)`.

Here is the code:

```
FTPSClient().apply {
        trustManager = TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager()

        connect(ftpHostName, ftpPort)

        if (login(ftpUser, ftpPassword)) {
            setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
            enterLocalPassiveMode()
            execPBSZ(0)
            execPROT("P")

            bufferSize = 1024

            var success = false
            resources.openRawResource(updateContainer.resource).use { input ->
                success = storeFile(updateContainer.remoteFileName, input)
                // todo javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x737c1ef588: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
            }

            logout()
            disconnect()

            if(success) {
                // ...
            }
        } else {
            // ...
        }
}
```

Here is the history log:

```
V: FTPS/receive/220 you're at home
V: FTPS/sent/AUTH TLS
V: FTPS/receive/234 AUTH TLS successful
V: FTPS/sent/USER randomuser
V: FTPS/receive/331 Password required for randomuser
V: FTPS/sent/PASS randompassword
V: FTPS/receive/230 Welcome !
V: FTPS/sent/TYPE I
V: FTPS/receive/200 Type set to I
V: FTPS/sent/PBSZ 0
V: FTPS/receive/200 PBSZ 0 successful
V: FTPS/sent/PROT P
V: FTPS/receive/200 Protection set to Private
V: FTPS/sent/PASV
V: FTPS/receive/227 Entering Passive Mode (...).
V: FTPS/sent/STOR xyz.mender
V: FTPS/receive/150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for xyz.mender
```

So the connection seems to work, however as soon as I try to upload the file, I get the exception:

```
E: org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
        at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:136)
```

which is cause by:

```
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x73d1256688: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.write(NativeSsl.java:425)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLOutputStream.write(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:626)
```

The server disables session reuse (`TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired`) so this is not the issue.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Edit: When trying to upload the file via FileZilla, it does work. However I do have to explicitly trust the unknown server certificate.
Could it be that `trustManager = TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager()` does not do what I think it does? And if so, could anyone provide me with an example on how to create the `SSLContext` in order to trust the server certificate (I do have access to the server's `.crt` file).